Why the \VerbatimInput of the .aux file is empty?
The following MCE shows that the .aux file, although found, produces an empty \VerbatimInput. Why?
\begin{filecontents}[noheader,force]{\jobname.txt}
\relax
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{\string\jobname.txt}}
This file has
\IfFileExists{\jobname.txt}{%
  been found and has the following framed content:
  \VerbatimInput[frame=single]{\jobname.txt}
  Nice, isn't it?
}{%
  not been found.
}

\section{\texttt{\string\jobname.aux}}
This file has
\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{%
  been found and has the following framed content:
  \VerbatimInput[frame=single]{\jobname.aux}
  Nice, isn't it?
}{%
  not been found.
}
\end{document}



Just a guess: because that file is currently open in LaTeX, you get the same if you do it with .log

as you are reading a file that is open for writing, the result is highly dependent on operating system file caching and is basically undefined.

When LaTeX processes \begin{document}, it inputs the .aux file (if it exists). This is the point where cross references, citations and other things from the previous run are made available for the current run (and most of them are also stored in memory).
After finishing this step, the .aux file is opened for writing, which “clears” it: the OS is informed that the file is open; write instructions to it are then forwarded to the OS, which does what it thinks best. Maybe it actually writes something in the file or it caches the write operations somewhere. In any case, the old contents is unavailable.
Maybe some OS would refuse to read from the file, because it knows about its unstable state; if the OS allows reading, it means that the write operations are cached and performed only when the file is closed. Or you get a mixture: maybe the OS does writes from time to time.
In any case, you'll get nothing useful from \VerbatimInput{\jobname.aux}: either nothing or a very partial contents. The OS might even throw an error (not likely with modern operating systems).
The only safe moments when the .aux file can be read in are: before \begin{document} or with the hook enddocument/afteraux, when the .aux file has just been closed. This is also the point where the new file is compared with what has been stored in memory in order to tell the user whether more runs are needed.
